# In SVG.Net how to set 'Fill' to 'None'?

Tags: .net, svg

Using SVG.Net (https://github.com/svg-net/SVG) how do I set Fill to None?
Currently trying **Fill=null**:

```
let borderRect =
    new SvgRectangle(
        X=SvgUnit(xPad + left), Y=SvgUnit(yPad + 0.f + float32 layer * tl.height),
        Width=SvgUnit(textWidth lblTxt), Height=SvgUnit(SvgUnitType.Pixel, fontSize * (16.f / 12.f) ),
        Stroke=new SvgColourServer(Color.Blue), Fill = null
    )
```

Which gives output:
`<rect x="50" y="250" width="87.85068" height="21.333334px" style="stroke:blue;" />`

Whereas I want:
`<rect x="50" y="250" width="87.85068" height="21.333334px" style="stroke:blue;fill:none" />`

Answer (score 1):

`Fill = Svg.SvgColourServer.None` seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

`Fill:none` equals `Fill = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent)`

or

`Fill = SvgPaintServer.None`